# React useState hook not updating state in async function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm encountering an issue with updating state using the useState hook in a React functional component. I have an async function (`getPalettesPosition`) that fetches data based on the current state (`paletteFilters`). However, although I've confirmed that `paletteFilters` is being updated correctly in the component, it doesn't seem to reflect the updated values within the async function call.

I've logged `paletteFilters` in various places within the component, including within the `useEffect` that depends on it, and it does show the updated values. However, when I call the `getPalettesPosition` function, it seems to use the initial state of `paletteFilters` rather than the updated one.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```js
// Component code
import * as React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import CustomSelect from "./CustomSelect";

function MyThing() {
  const palettesUrl = "https://example.com/co/pal/";

  const [userToken, setUserToken] = React.useState(() => {
    const storedUserData = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
    return storedUserData;
  });

  const [paletteFilters, setPaletteFilters] = React.useState({
    flavor: [],
    type: [],
    origin: [],
  });

  // Other useState and useEffect hooks...

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("from useEffect that depends on paletteFilters", paletteFilters);
    getPalettesPosition(userToken);
  }, [paletteFilters]);

  // Other useEffect hooks...

  let dataKeeper = [];

  const getPalettesPosition = async (token = null, manipulatedUrl = palettesUrl) => {
    try {
      // Logging the paletteFilters here shows the initial state, not the updated one
      console.log("From where I need it to be updated but it's not:", paletteFilters);
      
      // Fetching data based on paletteFilters...
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Fetch error:", error);
    }
  };

  // Other functions...

  return (
    <div>
      <CustomSelect
        options={["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]}
        onChange={handleSelectionChange}
      />
      <p>Selected Options: {selectedOptions.join(", ")}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyThing;
```

I've done this to make sure that the state is being updated, and it gets updated:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log("from useEffect that depends on paletteFilters", paletteFilters);
  getPalettesPosition(userToken);
}, [paletteFilters]);
```

However, it doesn't seem to reflect in the `getPalettesPosition` function.

**Here is my Sandbox Link**: [Link to Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/magical-stallman-6tjcxc?file=%2Fsrc%2FCustomSelect.js%3A31%2C1)

Comment: There is no call to `setPaletteFilters` anywhere in the code in the question (and questions **must** be self-contained, not relying on off-site links), nor is `setPaletteFilters` passed to anything not shown that might be calling it, so that's why no state update occurs. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Perhaps the code you've left out of the question is just *modifying* the `paletteFilters` object? If so, that's a basic error in React code, see [updating objects and arrays in state](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-objects-and-arrays-in-state). But that's just a guess, apologies if I'm mistaken.

Comment: did you see the sandbox I created?
the link is at the end of the question.
@t-j-crowder

Comment: Yes, I did. Did you see my sentence above saying *"...questions **must** be self-contained, not relying on off-site links..."*?  On SO, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Four reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future; and answers can't quote off-site code because we can't grant the license to it posting it would require. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question as suggested.

Comment: Great! Please ping me when you do. I'll help if I can. :-)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that getPalettesPosition function was initiated with the initial values of paletteFilters. So when the getPalettesPosition was called, it showed the initial values of paletteFilters and currently it has no way of getting the updated paletteFilters values.

To get the updated values of paletteFilters in getPalettesPosition, you must wrap getPalettesPosition inside a useCallback hook and add paletteFilters as the dependency. By this, everytime paletteFilters will be updated, the getPalettesPosition callback will have the latest values paletteFilters.

```
 const getPalettesPositionCB = useCallback(() => {
   // add getPalettesPosition here
  }, [paletteFilters]); // Add paletteFilters as a dependency
```

Comment: I've attempted to use the `useCallback` hook  in my React component. However, I'm afraid it's not working as expected.

I'm not sure if I'm using this hook the right way or not. You can check the sandbox I've created.( and also I'm calling it in `App.js` at line 46)

**Sandbox Link**: [Link to Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/magical-stallman-6tjcxc?file=%2Fsrc%2FCustomSelect.js%3A31%2C1)